# Graph of piecewise-defined function for limits (open or closed in the graph)

Tags: limits

I have some confusion with the graph representation of this limit function for x approaching 2 from left and right side

$f(x) =\begin{cases}x^2,&\text{if }x\le2  \\6-x, &\text{if } x>2\end{cases}$

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI4bL.png)

Should it not be it open at $x$ approaches $2$ for $6-x$ when $x >2$? But I see in the solution that it is closed.

Does that mean if piecewise-defined functions are approaching the same limit, they will be represented with a closed interval?

Comment: I think it's because if you plug in $2$ for $x^2$, you will get $4$, so $4$ is a valid value, so it is closed, not open.

Answer (score 1):

It is closed because if you plug in $2$ into the piecewise-defined function, $2\le2$, so you will have to plug in $2$ into $x^2$, which results in $2^2=4$. $4$ is a valid solution to the function, so it is part of the graph, which results in a solid dot at $y=4$.

Comment: So if x is less than 2 for the first case, instead of less than and equal to 2, then there would be a hole when limit approaches 2; which means the function is discontinuous at that value? right?

Comment: Yup, because $x=2$ isn't defined in the piecewise-defined function(it isn't part of the domain, either).